# How do I change my gmail app language to English without changing my iOS language setting?

Tags: gmail

I want to set my gmail iOS app to English without changing my iOS system-level language. Is it even possible?

Thanks,

Comment: What is your system level language?  Normally it's not possible for an iOS app to run in a different one, unless you see a language item in Settings > GMail, or the app has no localization for the system level language.

Comment: My system-level language is Chinese. And I can't find a language item in Settings > GMail. What I need is to switch to English, which is definitely existed in the app, without switching my system-level language to English.

Comment: Not possible as far as I know.  Ask the GMail folks to add this feature.